# How to do like below Text Layout

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputedittext

[image: Image link]

Please help how to do this design like this!

Comment: Try using TextInputLayout and a custom drawable for the border

Comment: use background image without text-

Comment: This is [Material Components for Android](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/). As a side note you should read [ask] for future uses .

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout), this should be enough:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="Remarks">


     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:hint="@string/form_username"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```